# Django form fails to validate

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this form that I am passing a parameter to disable or enable the fields based on certain user clicking a particular hyper link.

**URL**

```
path("update-request/<str:pk>/", update_request, name="update_request"),
path("update-request/<str:pk>/<str:action>", update_request, name="update_request"),
```

views.py

```
def create_new_request(request, action=None):
    description_form = DescriptionForm(action=action)
```

forms.py

```
class DescriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = "description"
    ....
    
    def __init__(self, action=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DescriptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(action)
```

example hyperlink:
New Request

My problem starts when I want to save the data to the database, I get all fields are displayed as being required even when data is in them. removing the `action` from DescriptionForm.**init** stops the problem, how do I circumvent this issue? The reason I needed to add the `action` in init is because I need to enable of disable fields if a condition is met.

```
def __init__(self, action=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DescriptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if action == "new_request" or "review":
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].disabled=True
```

My errors look like this:
title

```
This field is required.
category
This field is required.
job_description
This field is required.
urgent_request
This field is required.
detailed_job_description
This field is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) of the object through form to resolve this issue. Like this:

```
def create_new_request(request, pk, action=None):
    description = Description.objects.get(pk=pk)
    description_form = DescriptionForm(action, instance=description)
```

And update the form as well:

```
def __init__(self, action=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DescriptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if action in ["new_request","review"] and self.instance:
        # rest of the code
```

---

Even if a field is disabled, it does not mean it does not need data. If you can't provide data, then it is better to remove fields like:

```
for field in self.fields:
        del self.fields[field]
```

Or provide dummy data for validation.

Comment: I needed this for new creation. hence I have a three tables I want to populate or disable all together if it a user follows a particular url. passing the action gives field errors in template and form is invalid.

Comment: @CynthiaOnyilimba Please see the updated answer